# Assign only if not already defined in Julia

Tags: julia

Is there simple Julia syntax for assigning to a variable only if it is undefined (or falsy)?  I mean something like Ruby's `x ||= NEW_VALUE`.  I have tried `x || x=NEW_VALUE` but it throws an error.  Barring easy syntax, what function can I use to check if a variable is defined?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the [`@isdefined`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.@isdefined) macro: `(@isdefined x) || (x = NEW_VALUE)`.

Comment: Stefan, you might want to update this now that `@isdefined x` is a thing

Answer (score 4):

I've prepared a macro to deal with that little inconvenience.

```
macro ifund(exp)
    local e = :($exp)
    isdefined(Main, e.args[1]) ? :($(e.args[1])) : :($(esc(exp)))   
end
```

Then in REPL:

```
julia> z
ERROR: UndefVarError: z not defined

julia> @ifund z=1
1

julia> z
1

julia> z=10
10

julia> @ifund z=2
10

julia> z
10
```

An example of interpolation:

```
julia> w
ERROR: UndefVarError: w not defined

julia> w = "$(@ifund w="start:") end"
"start: end"

julia> w
"start: end"
```

But, remember of the scope (`y` is in the scope of for-loop):

```
julia> y
ERROR: UndefVarError: y not defined

julia> for i=1:10 y = "$(@ifund y="") $i" end

julia> y
ERROR: UndefVarError: y not defined
```

Let me know if it works. I'm curious, because it's my first exercise with macros.

edited: Julia v1.0 adaptation done.

Comment: Update for 1.0: replace `isdefined(e.args[1])` with `isdefined(Main, e.args[1])`

Comment: @fredcallaway, Done.